# What's an elegant way to overload the >> operator for a new file type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, file-io, operator-overloading

I'm adding some new functionality to some legacy code. The existing code reads some data from a text file. In the new version I'm going to be reading in much more data and want to use binary files, and on top of that the program could be used on Linux or Windows with the same (external) data file, so I want to enforce a big-endian sense when reading the binary data.

To that end I've created a new input file stream type - inherited from ifstream - with an overloaded ">>" operator that reads the binary data from file, interpreting it as big-endian. So far so good.

Now, when I'm reading data from file, I need to choose which type of input file stream object to create: regular ifstream when dealing with the old text files, or my new "iBinFile" type when dealing with the new binary files. The only solution I can come up with to this is to have two different pieces of code, one for the old type and one for the new type, which are identical apart from the input file stream type:

```
if (szFileName.compare(szFileName.size()-3,3,"bin")==0) {
    iBinFile inFile(szFileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << szFileName <<" file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit (-1);
    }
    while(!inFile.eof())
        inFile >> data;
}
else {
    ifstream inFile(szFileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << szFileName <<" file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit (-1);
    }
    while(!inFile.eof())
        inFile >> data;
}
```

But I feel like since iBinFile is derived from ifstream there should be a way to do it where the `if` statement only determines the file type and everything else is in common. If I was deriving iBinFile from my own class then I could make the ">>" operator virtual, but since it's not I don't know what the solution is, if there is one.

Comment: Just one thing, `while(!inFile.eof())` is a NO NO!! Please do `while(inFile >> data) { /* do stuff with data */}` instead.

Comment: Binary files **are not** portable. Again: binary files **are not** portable. You're asking for major headaches if you do this; endianness is just one of the issues you'll have to deal with. You'll also have to sort out different sizes for the same type and different binary representations of values. Not to mention totally unidiomatic use of `>>`, which in normal usage does **formatted** input (i.e. from a text file).

Comment: @PeteBecker A binary file can be just as portable as a text file.  In both cases, you specify a format (or use an existing one like XDR or BER), and write and read that format.  After all, a number of portable formats (e.g. JPEG, MP3, etc.) are binary, and I've communicated between IBM mainframes and PC's in binary as well (with a format which defined floating point to be represented in BCD).

Comment: @JamesKanze - I stand by what I said: you have to deal with different sizes for the same type and different binary representations of values in addition to endianness. Putting protocol names on top of that doesn't change the underlying issues.

Comment: @PeteBecker You have to define the representation of the types in yoru binary format, yes.  And you'll have to ensure that your functions to write and to read conform to the format you've defined.  That can be done portable, however; both BER and XDR are widespread, and BER is regularly used to communicate between processors with radically different architectures.

Answer (score 2):

The abstraction for all of the current iostream classes is
formatted text.  You do *not* want to derive from any of the
`std::istream` or `std::ostream` classes; you want to create
your own hierarchy.  You probably do want to derive from
`std::basic_ios<char>`, for its error handling and `streambuf`
management.  Similarly, do probably do want to use `streambuf`
and its derived classes.

Comment: And then wrap both in a common extractor class that can take either an `istream` or your binary reader...

Comment: That could be a bit tricky.  I'm not too sure how you'd go about it, given that none of the `>>` are virtual.

Comment: Wrap it -- create a new class with `virtual operator>>`.  Create two implementations, one of which uses `istream` and the other uses your binary reading class.  A typical name for such a class is an `InputArchive`.

Comment: The existing `operator>>` aren't members, and you don't even know all of them (since most will be for user defined types).  If you want to wrap `std::ostream` (something I do occasionally), you'll need to make `operator>>` a template.  Which means that it cannot be virtual.

Comment: +1 for identifying the istream and ostream are formatted text classes.